# Can you add a WMTS as a GeoServer Data Source?

Tags: geoserver, wmts

From [this GeoServer tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/gettingstarted/postgis-quickstart/index.html), (under "Creating a store") I can only see Vector, Database and Raster data types as the only possible data sources. But I was wondering if a Web Mapping service such as a WMTS could be added as a source?

Comment: Geoserver can't, but [Mapserver can](http://mapserver.org/input/raster.html#supported-formats), because `Since version 6.2, Mapserver raster input support is through the GDAL raster library only.` And one of GDAL's supported formats is ..[WMTS](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wmts.html).

Comment: That said, I'm curious why you're compelled to proxy an existing WMTS endpoint through Geoserver.. do you simply need to launder the domain to prevent [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issues?

Comment: Normally that is done because the remote WMTS is not serving data in a CRS you need. Reprojection is a common driver for cascading.

Comment: Yes, it's mainly a client setup issue. We have a WMTS map tile service and client has a GeoServer hub which they want everything to proxy through, including our map tiles. The only way I see around it is to expose our tiles as a WMS (through the GeoWebCache?) but it's a long-winded process to start with tiles, glue them together as WMS and end up with the same tiles again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it could be added with some programming work, but right now GeoServer can only cascade WMS.

Comment: [`The standard GeoServer installation supports the loading and serving of the following data formats: *GeoTIFF  *GTOPO30  *WorldImage  *ImageMosaic`](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/data/raster/index.html)

Comment: WMS is supported as well by default but through another data store.

Comment: With GeoServer 2.12.x it will be possible: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/cascaded/wmts.html